# Error creating bean - Inject Configuration-Class in Service does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I try to implement a REST-Service like in this tutorial: 
[Tutorial](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-file-upload-download-rest-api-example/)

But I got this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileStorageService' defined in file: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.airgnb.service.FileStorageService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.airgnb.service.FileStorageService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Service-Class:

```
@Service
public class FileStorageService {

    private final Path fileStorageLocation;

    @Autowired
    public FileStorageService(FileStorageProperties fileStorageProperties) {
        this.fileStorageLocation = Paths.get(fileStorageProperties.getUploadDir())
            .toAbsolutePath().normalize();

        try {
            Files.createDirectories(this.fileStorageLocation);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new FileStorageServiceException("Could not create the directory where the uploaded files will be stored.", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Configuration-Class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "file")
public class FileStorageProperties {

    private String uploadDir;

    public String getUploadDir() {
        return uploadDir;
    }

    public void setUploadDir(String uploadDir) {
        this.uploadDir = uploadDir;
    }
}
```

The app is also annotated like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({FileStorageProperties.class})
public class TestApp implements InitializingBean {
```

I think the only thing which differs is that I use an application.yml instead of an application.properties, but I defined the properties similar to the tutorial, but just in yml style.

I have no idea why the `FileStorageProperties` is not injected and therefore the `FileStorageService` can't be created.

I tried already to annotate the app with `@Import(FileStoroageProperties.class)` and also some other ways of dependency injection like field injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `FileStorageProperties` was not injected. The error would indicate that no Bean of type `FileStorageProperties` was found.
You just have a `NullPointerException` inside the constructor.

I think `fileStorageProperties.getUploadDir()` returned `null`.

Have you set the property `file.uploadDir` in your application.yml or application.properties?

Comment: It was set in the application.yml but not in the test/application.yml.